# Combined MySQL query help - 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table `rosters` and a table `members`. They are setup like this:

```
rosters table
id     team     member
 1     1        1
 2     1        2
 3     1        3

members table
id     name     last_active
 1     Dan      1454815000
 2     Ewan     1454817500
 3     Cate     1454818369
```

I need to fetch all rows in `rosters` where team=1. Then, I need to take all those returned results and use the `member` column to fetch the largest `last_active` value from `members` where `id` is in that list of results returned from `rosters`

This is how I would do it in PHP, but I'm sure there's a way to just use a more efficient query.

```
$rosterList = $db->query('SELECT * FROM rosters WHERE team=1');
$lastActive = 0;
foreach($rosterList as $roster) {
    $activity = $db->query('SELECT last_active FROM members WHERE id='.$roster['team']);
    if ( $activity > $lastActive )
        $lastActive = $activity;
}

if ( $lastActive > time()-60 )
    echo 'team is currently online';
```

It would be nice if it could just return one result with the latest `last_active` column but if it returns all matches in the `members` table that would be fine too.

Comment: I think I probably understand your requirement, but your sample `members` table does not have more than one `last_active` value (or more than one row) per `id` so it isn't clear why you need the greatest `last_active`. Can you update the `members` sample so it is more representative, and also provide a table of what query output you expect?

Comment: Also, do you actually need to use the other column values from the `rosters` table in your output? Your example PHP uses `SELECT *`, but if you don't actually need those columns it simplifies the query a little.

Comment: I have updated the member table with different times. No I do not need to output any of the values, and the only value I'm using for comparison is the last_active column in the members table.

Comment: But is it the greatest `last_active` time for one member on the team, or do you want the `last_active` time for _each_ team member? If for each, please add additional rows per member in the `members` table.

Comment: Why you are not using order by clause in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following solution:

```
$result_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rosters as r INNER JOIN members as m on r.member=m.id AND r.team = '1' ORDER BY last_active DESC LIMIT 1");

$lastActive = 0;

if($result_array)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_array,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $lastActive = $result_array['last_active'];
    }
}       

if ( !empty($lastActive) && $lastActive > time()-60 )
    echo 'team is currently online';
```

Answer (score 2):

By using an `ORDER BY` (descending) on that last_actie column, then limiting to just 1 row, you get access to the whole member row.

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8026f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE members
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `last_active` int)
;

INSERT INTO members
    (`id`, `name`, `last_active`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Dan', 1454815000),
    (2, 'Ewan', 1454817500),
    (3, 'Cate', 1454818369)
;

CREATE TABLE rosters
    (`id` int, `team` int, `member` int)
;

INSERT INTO rosters
    (`id`, `team`, `member`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 1, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    m.*
from members m
join rosters r on m.id = r.member
where r.team = 1
order by m.last_active DESC
limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8026f/2/0)**:

```
| id | name | last_active |
|----|------|-------------|
|  3 | Cate |  1454818369 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused why you are retrieving rows from `members` where the `id` value matches the `team` value from `rosters`.  Seems like you would want to match on the `member` column.

You can use a *join* operation and an aggregate function. To get the largest value of `last_active` for all members of a given `team`, using the `member` column, something like this:

```
  SELECT MAX(m.last_active) AS last_active
    FROM members m
    JOIN rosters r
      ON r.member = m.id
   WHERE r.team = 1
```

To do the equivalent of the original example, using the `team` column (and again, I don't understand why you would do this, because it doesn't look right):

```
SELECT MAX(m.last_active) AS last_active
  FROM members m
  JOIN rosters r
    ON r.team = m.id
 WHERE r.team = 1
```

---

The `MAX()` aggregate function in the SELECT list, with no `GROUP BY` clause, causes all of the rows returned to be "collapsed" into a single row. The largest value of `last_active` from the rows that satisfy the predicates will be returned.

You can see how the join operation works by eliminating the `MAX()` aggregate...

```
SELECT m.last_active
     , m.id           AS member_id
     , m.name         AS member_name
     , r.member
     , r.team
     , r.id AS roster_id
  FROM members m
  JOIN rosters r
    ON r.member = m.id
 WHERE r.team = 1
 ORDER BY m.last_active DESC
```

Comment: Yes I want to match id to the member value of the returned data from the roster table. I think your answer is correct and suits my needs. Thank you.